# teams bot, how to configure messaging endpoint dynamically?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I don't know if this is a valid question or not,but what I need is

i want to create a bot which has different messaging endpoints for different organizations so that i can manage the code for different organizations separately. Because my code which is written in nodejs may want to connect to the respective databases and servers of the client organizations

Like is there a dynamic way of initializing messaging endpoint at runtime as a one time process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have the bot have multiple endpoints like this, unfortunately, but in Teams each message to your bot contains a "channelData" element, which includes a "tenant" property, which in turn contains an "id" property,  something like this

```
...
    "channelData": {
    ...
        "tenant": {
            "id": "[tenant id value]"
        },
    ...
    },
...
```

you can access this through the bot framework, and make decisions based on that (e.g. what database to connect to, etc.).

Comment: that is what i first thought about, but using a single server to  channel all the incoming requests from all the organizations? would this cause the server to overload?

Comment: well, it depends on how much traffic you expect, and also where/how you are hosting your bot. If it's in a cloud service like Azure, you can scale it up as necessary. You could also put a load balancing system in front of your bot, i.e. between your bot and the bot service, that can help handle the scaling

Comment: i am planning to host it in AWS or azure, so yes, it would do fine, I would just take all incoming requests in the mainserver then redirect to the corresponding apps and collect back the responses and send it back to respective teams interface